# B2C verification emails do not deliver

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a situation where the verification emails sent from a B2C tenant at sign-up do not deliver to users with email addresses for certain domains like free.fr, neuf.fr, laposte.net, club-internet.fr, etc.
Could the use of a third-party email provider address this issue?

Comment: Thanks @Nana and Please follow this document for allow/deny email domain - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list

Comment: Are you certian it’s not ending up in their spam filter? We should not be blocking sending emails out on the AAD B2C service side.

Comment: No the mails are not going to their Spam folder, it's one of the first things they were asked to confirm with the users.